# Shrink browser content to browser window size

Tags: java, gwt, highcharts, uibinder

am wondering, if there is a solution for shrinking a charts within browser window, i.a if i resize my browser window my application with highcharts do it well to, it's also resized to the browser window size, but if i shrink my browser window, the app with charts doesn't shrink in size to the browser window size, it only do it when refresh the whole web page, but i need it to be able to do it automatically when you shrink the browser window, the window content also shrinks to the browser sizes, am using java with *UiBinder DockLayoutPanel* inside *RootLayoutPanel*. Would be very thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: This seems more suitable for JavaScript or some clever CSS

Comment: You can catch $(window).resize() / call chart.setSize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specific code examples a specific answer is difficult to give. But to react to browser resize you need to implement the `onResize()` method. The layout panels you name call this method on children that implement the interface `RequireResize`. So the panel with the chart should implement the `onResize()`, and resize the chart. Make sure the parent tree of this widget all implement `onResize()` or else the method won't be called.

Comment: thank you for the answer, would it be not resized, if i have verticalpanel, wich does not implements requireresize, inside scrollpanel, and this scrollpanel is in the center of the docklayoutpanel in my parent tree widgets

Comment: No it won't work, because it breaks the chain. The problem with  ScrollPanel is that the content is intended to keep a certain height and when the page becomes smaller a scrollbar is added. This is kind of opposite of resizing when it changes height. Therefore to get it to work with a scrollpanel is very difficult. Because the code doesn't know if it should resize or add a scrollbar. You would need to calculate it yourself what the size of the chart should be given a certain window size. Also it's better to use a FlowPanel(HTML div) instead of a VerticalPanel(HTML table)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible example (note that I am not using moxie but another wrapper ) : http://data-dragon-766.appspot.com/

You can find the class responsible for rendering the chart.

https://github.com/highcharts4gwt/highcharts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/highcharts4gwt/client/view/widget/HighchartsLayoutPanel.java